# Sublime Text 3 - How to make a plugin work with one file type

Tags: html, css, plugins, sublimetext3

I am new to Sublime Text 3 and web development. I wanted to use Emmet and Hayaku. 
Emmet seems to be better for HTML and Hayaku better for CSS.

So, I wanted to make Emmet only work with HTML files and Hayaku only with CSS files -> avoid conflicts.

I bet it has to do with Preferences.sublime-settings file but not really sure what I do have to modify to make it work the way I do.

This is not a Emmet/Hayaku specific question. I am also interested in knowing how to make any plugin work with the file types I want.

Comment: Do you know any python?

Comment: As I said "I am new to Sublime Text 3 and web development". So the answer is "No".